# Asp calendar control

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp page. I need to have a calendar control in it.My requirement is to poplulate a textbox with selected Calendar date where the textbox is dynamically generated. So please can anyone help me out. How can I do that?

Comment: do you know javascript or not?

Comment: you have asked 4 question till date and you have not accepted any answer and you have not give any upvote Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a classic ASP calendar sample code for you [LINK](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3293/a-calendar-class-for-classic-asp/)

Comment: Hi Thomas, Actually my requirement is in asp page. So can you help me out using any asp control. I mean is there any asp control?

Comment: As well my requirement is: how can I select the date from the calendar control and populate that in a textbox.

Comment: Thanks, but how this will take the date and popluate in a textbox

Comment: @dipa: if you know javascript then you can use [this Calendar](http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/)